# CH340G based USB to UART adapter - Pinouts - Can't find schematics

Tags: serial, uart, ch340

[This](https://minielektro.dk/dev-10053.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwyryUBhBSEiwAGN5OCIxnaU5lCMS4IczQlnlLFWL2wgJWJj6RQ1qy8xyN4i50NNoEWv6rqBoCLuUQAvD_BwE) is the board I will be referring to.
[image: Board image]

There are different variations of it (with built in buttons etc.) but they all seem to be based on the CH340 chip.

My problem is, that I do not know what the pinouts on the board stand for. I cannot find any schematics for the adapter (I can find some for the CH340). Does anyone have a clue as to what the different pins are for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module appears to be designed for communicating with the [ESP8266 ESP-01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) board. The pinout for the ESP-01 is shown below, taken from a typical [datasheet](https://www.microchip.ua/wireless/esp01.pdf):

[image: ESP-01 Pinout]

[Updated]The arrow on the CH340 board next to the yellow header indicates the connection orientation. The bulk of the ESP-01 goes on the side of the header pointed to by the arrow, covering the CH340 board, as shown below.

[image: connection orientation]

Information on the WCH CH340 product set including the G model is [here](http://www.wch-ic.com/products/CH340.html).

[image: CH340G pinout]

There is plenty of online information on getting started with the ESP8266 ESP-01 using the Arduino IDE. A good example is at [instructables.com](https://www.instructables.com/Getting-Started-With-Esp-8266-Esp-01-With-Arduino-/).

The other model variations you mentioned (with built in buttons) are probably in response to a known problem with this board when flashing ESP-01s. See [here](https://www.instructables.com/USB-to-ESP-01-Board-Adapter-Modification/) for more info.

Comment: The orientation is indicated by the arrow on the board

Comment: Thanks @Majenko, yes I guessed that. Not being familiar with the board / ESP-01 I wasn’t sure how to interpret the arrow. Is it pointing to the side on which the bulk of the ESP-01 board should be?

Comment: Yes. The ESP-01 covers the main body of the board.

Comment: @RowanP Thank you very much for the help! Do you know by any chance, if it is possible to use it for general UART/Serial communication? Specifically, if I simply connect TX to my device's RX and vise versa, would there be anything against doing this?

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump I have not used the board myself, but I’m confident you could use jumpers to connect the RX, TX, Gnd, and maybe Vcc as you would for any CH340 adapter.